# Upload file to CodeIgniter 2.14 and PHP 5.3.20 where exec() has been disabled

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload, exec

I was trying to upload some files to my app and it was working fine on localhost, but when I ran my app on my host, my code failed with this in the logs:

```
Severity: Warning  --> exec() has been disabled for security reasons /home/public_html/system/libraries/Upload.php 1075
```

After doing some digging I found out that even though `exec()` is disabled (which is a good practice btw), the function still exists. Therefore the check that CodeIgniter does, `function_exists('exec')` is useless since the function always exists, whether it's enabled or not.

Others had the same problem on stackoverflow but their solutions didn't work for me. I'm writing this because I would like to offer here the solution that I came up with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cloned the `Upload.php` library to my `application/libraries` path and then edited line 1064 from

```
if (DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR !== '\\')
```

to

```
if (false && DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR !== '\\')
```

This line normally tests if the host is a windows system, which would skip trying to use `exec()`, `shell_exec()`, and `popen()`, and instead use the function `mime_content_type()` which is enough for my application. By adding false I make sure the code always falls back to that function.